# How to make appropriate statements concerning simultaneity or sequence of pitches?

Tags: special-relativity

This answer [The example of relativity of simultaneity given by Einstein](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80773/the-example-of-relativity-of-simultaneity-given-by-einstein/80776#80776) to a recent question related to [Einstein's thought-experimental definition of (how to determine) simultaneity](http://archive.org/details/relativitythespe00einsuoft#chapters.8.and.9) contained the following statement:

> Suppose two people, $C$ and $D$, stand equal distances from you and are known to pitch balls at exactly the same speed. With everyone standing at rest, $C$ and $D$ each toss you a ball. You get the ball from $C$ *before* the one from $D$. This is not a logical inconsistency. It simply means $C$ threw a ball *before* $D$ **in your reference frame** [emphasis added].

I believe that I understand the described setup and the conclusion ("*It simply means $C$ threw a ball before $D$*") as such. But I question whether it is necessary to add the qualification "*in your reference frame*".

Carefully applying Einstein's definition of (how to determine) simultaneity, as referenced above, which for the given setup involves a suitable observer "*at the midpoint between* $C$ and $D$", is there even any reference frame at all (necessarily other than "*your reference frame*") "in which" $C$ threw a ball *simultaneous to* $D$ throwing a ball ?

Or is there even any reference frame at all (again necessarily other than "*your reference frame*") "in which" $C$ threw a ball *after* $D$ ?

(If there are no such reference frames, then the qualification "*in your reference frame*" is apparently not necessary; and, indeed, it would seem inappropriate and misleading to add such a qualification as if it were necessary.)

Comment: user12262 wrote: "_Carefully applying Einstein's definition of (how to determine) simultaneity, as referenced above, [...]_" -- Well, instead of just being disappointed of others not being as careful as specified or intended, I may try to phrase my question more carefully myself: [Does a "midpoint between" two members of an inertial system belong to the same inertial system?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81126/does-a-midpoint-between-2-members-of-an-inertial-system-belong-to-the-same-is).

Comment: You are just arguing with everyone at cross purposes. The answer to your last question depends entirely on what you mean by 'belong'. The fact is that there is a midpoint between C and D in their rest frame, and it is stationary in their rest frame. If you want to call that 'belonging' to their rest frame, then fine. There are also moving points that are halfway between C and D in other inertial frames in which C and D are moving. In general, those moving  halfway points will not be coincident with each other or with the midpoint in the rest frame of C and D.

Answer (score 2):

Try thinking in terms of events and spacetime.  Event C is the toss of the ball from pitcher C and Event D is the toss of the ball from pitcher D.  In your frame of reference, C occurs before D.

Now, if events C and D have a spacelike interval (meaning they are farther apart in space than in time), then there is a frame of reference in which they are simultaneous and there are frames of reference in which D occurs before C.

But, if events C and D have a timelike interval (meaning they are farther apart in time than in space), or a light-like interval (meaning they are as far apart in time as in space), then there is no frame of reference in which C does not occur before D.

[Here is an interactive spacetime diagram](http://www.trell.org/div/minkowski.html) that you can "play" with to help make these results visually clear.

Comment: Alfred Centauri: "_Try thinking in terms of events and spacetime._" -- Fine, as long as the notion "_event_" is carefully distinguished from other notions appearing in the quoted statement. "_Event C is the toss of the ball from pitcher C [...]_" -- Already your notation starts to conflate "_event_" and "one particular participant of an event (and perhaps also of other events)": "pitcher $C$". May I therefore suggest (also trying to be consistent with notation used in the reference): ... (to be continued.)

Comment: (contd.) ... May I suggest: call "$A$" the ball thrown by $C$; call "$\mathcal{E}_{AC}$" the event in which both $A$ and $C$ took part ($C$ tossing $A$, and $A$ being tossed by $C$; and perhaps even other participants, such as a passing butterfly clapping its wings, or a passing muon decaying); call "$C_A$" pitcher $C$'s indication of tossing $A$; call "$A_C$" ball $A$'s indication of being tossed by $C$. Likewise call "$B$" the ball thrown by pitcher $D$, introduce event "$\mathcal{E}_{BD}$" and so on. ... (to be continued.)

Comment: (contd.): Finally, note that the quoted statement and my question is specificly about the pitchers ("_people_") $C$ and $D$ and their indications (pitches, or "acts or throwing", $C_A$ and $D_B$); and not necessarily about indications of any other participants in events $\mathcal{E}_{AC}$ or $\mathcal{E}_{BD}$).

Comment: p.s. user12262 wrote: "_May I suggest: call "$A$" the ball thrown by $C$ ... Likewise call "$B$" the ball thrown by pitcher_ $D$". -- That's unfortunately a poor choice of names for the balls under consideration because name pair "$A$, $B$" is [typically](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/On_the_Electrodynamics_of_Moving_Bodies_%281920_edition%29) given to (and suggestive of) two participants who are at rest to each other; which these balls are not. So the ball thrown by $D$ might be better called "$E$", for instance; and the event in which $D$ and $E$ took part correspondingly $\mathcal{E}_{DE}$.

Comment: @user12262 In relativity the term "event" has a specific meaning: it's a point in spacetime. And being a point it's instantaneous, and it has no spatial extent.

Comment: @PM 2Ring: "_In relativity the term "event" has a specific meaning:_" -- Indeed: there, one "event" means one ["_space-time coincidence_"](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/165?highlightText=coincidences); such as the coincidence of several "_material points_" passing each other, or any one participant collecting [several perceptions together](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/283?highlightText=perceives). "_it's a point in spacetime. [...] instantaneous, and it has no spatial extent._" -- Thus it's well **represented** as one element of a manifold.