# Does a "midpoint between" 2 members of an inertial system belong to the same IS?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames

[This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/80776) to a recent question related to [Einstein's thought-experimental definition of (how to determine) simultaneity](https://archive.org/details/relativitythespe00einsuoft#chapters.8.and.9) contained the following statement:

> Suppose two people, $C$ and $D$, stand equal distances from you and are known to pitch balls at exactly the same speed. With everyone standing at rest, $C$ and $D$ each toss you a ball. You get the ball from $C$ *before* the one from $D$. This is not a logical inconsistency. It simply means $C$ threw a ball *before* $D$ **in your reference frame** [emphasis added].

I believe that I understand the described setup and the conclusion ("*It simply means $C$ threw a ball *before* $D$*") as such.
But I ([still](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81014/)) question whether it is necessary to add the qualification "*in your reference frame*" (above and beyond pointing out the relevant participants $C$ and $D$ themselves), or whether that is superfluous.

Since Einstein's definition essentially requires to identify a "midpoint between" the two participants under consideration who are at rest to each other (such as "between [railroad ties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railroad_tie) $A$ and $B$", in the reference linked above; or "between pitchers $C$ and $D$" in the quoted statement) therefore I'd like to know:

Is it necessary to refer to
"the midpoint between pitchers $C$ and $D$ in your (and $C$'s and $D$'s) inertial reference frame"
in order to identify it uniquely,
instead of simply referring to "the midpoint between pitchers $C$ and $D$"?

Is there a "midpoint between pitchers $C$ and $D$ in an (inertial) reference frame other than your's (and $C$'s and $D$'s)" ?
And if so, is such a "midpoint between pitchers $C$ and $D$ in an (inertial) reference frame other than your's (and $C$'s and $D$'s)" different from
"the midpoint between pitchers $C$ and $D$ in your (and $C$'s and $D$'s) inertial reference frame"?

(If not, then the qualification "*in your reference frame*" is apparently superfluous; and, indeed, it would seem inappropriate and misleading to add such a qualification as if it were necessary.)

Answer (score 3):

> But I (still) question whether it is necessary to add the
>   qualification "in your reference frame" (above and beyond pointing out
>   the relevant participants C and D themselves), or whether that is
>   superfluous.

This has already been [addressed and answered](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81014/how-to-make-appropriate-statements-concerning-simultaneity-or-sequence-of-pitche/81019#81019) despite your evident refusal to accept that it has.

There *are* circumstances in which you, at the midpoint and in the same IRF as the pitchers, receive the ball from C first but, as observed from another IRF, *C does not throw the ball first.*

Thus, the qualification "in your reference frame" is not necessarily superfluous.

Observe (from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity)):

[image]

"*Events A, B, and C occur in different order depending on the motion of the observer. **The white line represents a plane of simultaneity** being moved from the past to the future.*"

Comment: Alfred Centauri: "_[...] but, as observed from another IRF, [...]_" -- Please try to directly address the stated question(s) and/or to directly refer to the definition in the linked reference. Are you really suggesting that there exists (at least) one member of another IRF (other than the IRF of $C$ and $D$) who should be called "midpoint between" (or "middle between") $C$ and $D$ ??, in order to give judgements about simultaneity (or sequence) specificly of $C$'s and $D$'s acts in the sense of Einstein's definition. If so: who? (in terms of $\beta$, distance $CD$ etc.)

Comment: @user12262, are you deliberately being obtuse?  Your argument is flawed.  Isn't it clear?  It does not logically follow from your midpoint "argument" that the qualification *in your reference frame* is superfluous.  I've already demonstrated *that the qualification is not superfluous* thus, your argument is flawed - period.

Comment: @user12262, to be more specific, *isn't it clear*, that the quoted, highlighted phrase in your question, that **in your reference frame** qualifies the phrase "C threw a ball *before* D" and not anything at all to do with the midpoint?  You seem to be obsessively focused on the the midpoint *for no reason at all*.

Comment: Alfred Centauri: "_that **in your reference frame** qualifies the phrase "C threw a ball before D"_" -- Agreed; obviously. "_and not anything at all to do with the midpoint_" -- ??? Of course it does: The term "_before_" in the quoted phrase requires a definition that (to quote the reference) _in every real case it must supply us with an empirical decision as to whether or not the conception that has to be defined is fulfilled._ Therefore: _an observer [should be] placed at the mid-point M of the distance [$CD$]_. (Clearly, defining "sequence" is closely related to defining "simultaneity".)

Comment: @user12262, the answer to the question of whether C throws first or not, as observed in an IFR, does not require that there be an observer at the midpoint - the midpoint observer is utterly irrelevant and obviously a major impediment to your understanding of the physics involved here.  The answer is determined by the reading of *Einstein synchronized clocks* co-located with each pitcher when each throws the ball.  *No middleman required*.

Comment: Alfred Centauri: 1. Once again, please address the stated question(s), before discussing their possible relevance. 2. Note, as pointed out elsewhere already, that the questions and the quote **are not** concerned with entire events. There is no mentioning of "pitcher $C$ throwing ball $A$ **and** a passing locomotive $L$ whisteling **and** a passing fluorescent molecule $F$ changing its excitation state **and** ... ball $A$ indicating its release" **jointly**, but only of acts/indications/times of individual participants (pitcher $C$ throwing $A$, and similarly $D$). (To be contd.)

Comment: Alfred Centauri: 3. If you find it necessary to refer to entire events, and to give them distinct names, then please let your notation express that you understand the distinction between an event and individual participants in an event; using distinct single letters for distinct individual participants (such as $C$ and $D$ in the quoted statement), and naming the event just described for instance $\mathcal{E}_{ACFL}$. "_the midpoint observer is utterly irrelevant [...]_" -- This opinion of yours warrants another careful question.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not about the midpoint between two pitchers, but the midpoint between two ***events.*** One of the events is C throwing a ball, and the other event is D throwing a ball. The midpoint is needed to determine whether the two ***events*** where simultaneous or not, and which event happened first. In the normal "Einsteinian" clock synchronisation method, the two events are only simultaneous in a reference frame, if light from the two events arrives at the same time at the midpoint between the events in that reference frame.

That is, at the moment C releases the ball, mark C's location in your reference frame. Then, at the moment D releases the ball, mark D's location. Now, take a ruler and measure the distance between those two locations to find the midpoint.

I think it is easy to see that where that midpoint is, and what happens to it,  depends on the reference frame. For an observer on a train, the midpoint is stationary to the train, and therefore moves with the train. For an observer on the platform that midpoint is stationary to the platform.

Comment: fishinear: "_[...] mark C's location in your reference frame._" -- According to the OP question, C and I are supposed to "stand a certain distance from each other". Consequently we are at rest to each other, i.e. members of the same inertial system. "The mark of C's location in my inertial frame" is therefore plainly and constantly: C himself. Likewise: "_Then, at the moment D releases the ball, mark D's location._" -- That's plainly and constantly: D himself. It remains the explicit OP problem: Does the midpoint between pitchers C and D belong to the same inertial system?. [continued]

Comment: fishinear: "_[...] take a ruler and measure the distance between those two [...] to find the midpoint._" -- Is "the midpoint between C and D" consequently an identifiable participant, let's call her M, who "stands a certain distance from C" and also "stands a certain distance from D" ? (even more specifically, with distance CM half of the distance CD, and distance DM equally half of the distance CD) -- Then M is necessarily at rest wrt. C as well as D, i.e. also a member of the same inertial system. So the answer to my OP question is: No additional specification of reference frame is required.

Comment: @user12262 The midpoint between the **events** is required to determine whether those **events** where simultaneous, I added a clarification to the answer for that. If an observer M is standing in the middle between C and D, and is stationary wrt. C and D, then yes, M is at the midpoint between C and D at any time in any reference frame. But if the balls are not thrown at the same time in some reference frame, then M is NOT (necessarily) at the midpoint between the **events** in that reference frame.

Comment: Or said in a different way, which position of M would you take as the midpoint, if C,D, and M are moving wrt. your reference frame, and if C and D do not throw the ball at the same time? The position of M when C throws the ball, or the position of M when D throws the ball, or some other position?

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood the paragraph you have quoted. The phrase 'in your reference frame' refers to the timing of the events, not to the position of the person catching the balls. The phrase is justified because its purpose is to stress that the earlier timing of C's throw is a feature of your reference frame- in another frame, C and D may have thrown the balls at the same time.

ADDENDUM

If C and D throw balls at each other with a speed that is constant to every observer, then the midpoint between them is the point at which the balls meet if thrown simultaneously.

If you sit at the centre of a travelling railway carriage, and C and D stand at either end, then if C and D throw the balls simultaneously in your frame, the balls will meet where you are sitting.

If, however, C and D on the train throw balls at times that are simultaneous in the frame of the platform, the balls will meet some way behind you toward the rear of the train.

An observer on the platform, noting the point at which the balls met in the second case, will conclude that is was the midpoint between C and D at the time they threw the balls.

So both the relative timing of the throws, and the position of the midpoint between C and D, depend upon the choice of reference frame.

SECOND ADDENDUM

Your latest comment confirms that you stubbornly hold to the view that a midpoint should only be considered as such in a frame in which it and the distance it bisects are at rest. By the same logic, one would argue that the only lengths that should be considered as such are proper lengths, likewise times. If you persist in holding such contrary views, you will always be arguing with other physicists who, with abundant reason, disagree with them.

The answers to your questions are that yes, there is a midpoint between C and D in every inertial reference frame and that its position depends upon the velocity of C and D in the reference frame. Given that, it is not tautologous to add the condition 'in your reference frame' when referring to a midpoint, just as it is not tautologous to add the same condition when talking about distances, elapsed times, relative timings and so on.

Comment: Marco Ocram: "_[...] to stress that the earlier timing of C's throw_" -- i.e. occuring earlier than D's throw -- "_is a feature of your reference frame_" -- The determination of timely order vs. simultaneity of C's and D's actions and indications is, according to [Einsteins definition](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/283?highlightText=mid), "a feature" of C, D, and of "the middle between" them. "_in another frame, C and D may have thrown the balls at the same time._" -- C and D are exclusively members of **their common inertial frame**, not of any other.

Comment: In spite of reading your comment three times, I cannot be sure I understand your point. C and D throw balls at different times in one inertial frame and at the same time in another. The midpoint between them in their inertial frame is what it is. The midpoint as judged by someone in another inertial frame will be elsewhere, owing to the effects of the relativity of simultaneity.

Comment: I have added a comment to my answer which might help.

Comment: Marco Ocram: "_C and D throw balls at different times in one inertial frame and at the same time in another._" -- That's an absurd alternative, since C and D belong together to exactly one inertial frame. (And the OP implies that their throws are not simultaneous.) Members of other inertial frames have been passed by C, or by D, resp.; surely there's some inertial frame, of which neither C nor D are members, but, say, containing members A and B, such that A's indication of being passed by C just as C threw a ball was simultaneous to B's indication of being passed by D just as D threw a ball.

Comment: Marco Ocram: "_The midpoint between [C and D] in their inertial frame is what it is._" -- This leaves the possibility that C and D also have other midpoints which are not members of the same inertial frame to which C and D belong; perhaps even midpoints which aren't members of any inertial frame at all. (The exact operational procedure of how to identify a "midpoint" of a given pair of participants is relevant here.) "_The midpoint as judged by someone in another inertial frame [...]_" -- The (or a) midpoint of C and D must not be confused with the (or a) midpoint of A and B, for instance.

Comment: I don't understand your terminology. When you say a 'member' of a frame, do you just mean someone stationary in it?  You seem to be using the term midpoint to mean exclusively the midpoint between C and D in their rest frame. If you take the word to mean that, then you never have to add 'in their rest frame'. However, you then need to define a new term too mean the point that is halfway between C and D at a given moment in a frame moving relative to them.

Comment: Also, you seem to be suggesting that C and D can only throw balls in their rest frame, which is nonsense. I get the impression that either you don't understand aspects of SR or that you think about it using terms that mean something special to you and something different to others, as only those two reasons could account for the fact that you re not able to reach agreement with other physicists about relatively simple and well-established principles.

Comment: Marco Ocram: "_[...] your terminology_" -- Rindler's prescription: [_"An inertial frame is simply an infinite set of point particles sitting still in space relative to each other."_](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Special_relativity:_kinematics#Galilean_and_Lorentz_transformations). (Of course, "_sitting still_" would have to be defined more specifically.) "_[...] halfway between C and D at a given moment in a frame moving relative to them._" -- What exactly, or rather who exactly, would **you mean** by this? Perhaps **anyone** who **ever** met _the_ (IMHO unique) midpoint of C and D ?

Comment: Can you accept the concept of C and D moving through other reference frames? If so, in such a reference frame at a given point in time, where would observers in that frame say the halfway point between C and D lay? How would that compare to the position of the halfway point between them as measured in their rest frame?

Comment: Marco Ocram: "_[...] that C and D can only throw balls in their rest frame, [...]_" -- The OP specifies C and D as "standing equal distances from" someone, and indeed "standing at rest". Accordingly, C and D are each separately considered a member of an inertial system, a.k.a. rest frame. (And moreover C and D are jointly members of the same IS). Whatever C and D do or indicate is consequently called "in this inertial system". The balls, having been released and thrown away, are then not members of this IS any more; and "the process of throwing, as accelerating the ball" is neglected.

Comment: Marco Ocram: "_Can you accept the concept of C and D moving through other reference frames?_" -- Of course; for example wrt. the inertial system of A and B alluded to above. "_If so, in such a reference frame at a given point in time, where would observers in that frame say the halfway point between C and D lay?_" -- Surely they can and should refer to C and D's proper determination. And certainly not confuse with A and B's proper determinaton, for instance. "_How would that compare[...]_" -- The midpoint of C and D and the midpoint of A and B may have met each other once, in passing.

Comment: OK, we definitely are arguing at cross purposes. I asked you two questions and you've changed the subject without answering them. Why are you being evasive? Why not just answer the questions I put?

Comment: Marco Ocram: "_Why are you being evasive? [...]_" -- As far as you've been suggesting that different participants could possibly disagree on who constitutes the midpoint (or all distinguishable midpoints ?) between C and D, instead of everyone interested striving to obtain the very same result which C and D could have obtained themselves (provided they were capable of observing and evaluating their observational data just as you or me or the next guy), your suggestion is improper and is indeed not my interest. After all, the theory of relativity is rightly called "theory of invariants", too.