# A thought experiment in special relativity theory

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, observers

We have two sets: set No.1 and set No.2 as in this picture: 
[image]

The observer is fixed to set No.1 . He sees set No.1 motionless and observes set No. 2 approaching with velocity 100,000 m/s.

Each set has one lamp and two, so called, **touchers**. The ends of the lamp on set No. 1 is connected directly to the touchers. One end of the lamp on set No. 2 is connected to one end of a battery and the other end of the battery is connected to the other toucher.

Set No. 2 is approaching set No. 1 so that each toucher in each set will be touched twice by the touchers of the other set. There is no friction between touchers and nothing else slowing down the movements.

The observer on set No. 1 observes the distance between touchers in each set 10 meters. It seems the lamp on Set No. 1 will light up. But the lamp on set No. 2 will not light up. And an observer on No. 2 will be be sure that the energy of the battery is not used because there has been no closed circuit.

**My question**: Will set No. 2 slow down?

**Note 1**: the numbers in the picture is what an observer on set No. 1 calculates.

**Note 2**: ignore friction, interaction of wires (including magnetic field. electric field, etc), and so on. Only consider the energy that a lamp needs to light up and if it may slow down the movement to get the energy. Do not ignore the mass of the sets so  slowing down needs or produces energy.

**Note 3**: The experiment is designed such that an observer in set No. 1 will see the circuit is closed (because its touchers will be connected to the battery of set No. 2 simultaneously). But for an observer in set No. 2 the circuit will remain open. This is the main situation the experiment tries to create. So  yu can change the numbers (like 10 and 100000) if they are not good.

**Note 4:** The core of the question is the circuit part of which is moving. I think if lamp 1 lights up it cannot use the battery. It can only use the kinetic energy of set No. 2. This is why I'm asking if set No. 2 will slow down.

**Note 5:** the touchers are not like a sharp point. So electricity will have enough time to turn on the lamps.

---

**explanation:**
It seems from comments I have to explain the situation more carefully:

1. For set No. 1 the distance between (the centers of) the touchers in both sets is 10. So lamp 1 will feel the ends of a battery connected to its ends. So lamp 1 has to light up. Because the circuit is closed for it.
2. For set No. 2 the distances between (the centers of) the touchers in both sets are not the same. So the battery will never feel a closed circuit. So for sure, it will not release energy at all.
3. the lamp of set No. 1 will light up and the battery will not be used. So what is the source of energy which helps the lamp to turn on? There remains no other source of energy except the kinetic energy stored in set No. 2 (for Set. 1). So I think the lamp will hinder the motion of set No. 2 to gain some energy to light up. So it will slow down set No. 2.

Is this correct? if no how do you explain (1), (2) and (3) all holding together?

Comment: Minimus Heximus: "_My question: Will set No. 2 slow down?_" -- May I suggest that it was instead intended to ask: "Will set No. 2 light up?" ? (Also, considering that "the wiring" of set No. 1 might be thought of as having finite [capacitance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance), the answer could be plainly: "Yes." .) "_Note: the numbers in the picture is what an observer on set No. 1 calculates._" -- What's that calculation explicitly? Does the value $$\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{100000~\text{m/s}}{c}\right)^2} \lesssim 1$$ play a role in that calculation?

Comment: Minimus Heximus: "_your suggestion is the previous question linked. As the accepted answer there shows [...]_" -- Alright, I'll have a look at the link and especially [the accepted answer there (PSE/a/128527)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/128527). (Sorry that I hadn't already before submitting my above comment. Also: I find it disturbing and inconsiderate that some comments at PSE are deleted without any trace, and possibly, as I've experienced myself, even without consent of the respective authors.) "_By calculating I mean measuring._" -- Sure. And physicists should care about that.

Comment: Minimus Heximus: "_probably dmckee has deleted those comments to keep things tidy._" -- Possibly so. Nevertheless: one user's "_tidy_" may be another's "outrageous". If user dmckee, or any other particular user, prefers not to see some selected comments (or all comments) I wish that each would be given the possibility of `user:preference` settings for this purpose; without infringing on the availability of those comments for other users who wish to read and quote them. There should even be a setting **to adopt** dmckee's settings (regarding comments, or otherwise) for those who'd prefer that.

Comment: I deleted my comments.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus Are the touchers' plates that can be seen on set No.1 supposed to be point-like or they have a finite length?

Comment: Seems to be a slightly modified version of the classic [pole-barn paradox](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relativ/polebarn.html).

Comment: ‏‏‏@Phonon: they have short length which will let lamps turn on but not too long so that relativity can be ignored.

Comment: @KyleKanos: I can say no. Because the main problem is electricity in a partially moving circuit in the question above,

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: Debatable because I'd say the real issue is whether or not the "touchers" link together due to length contraction.

Comment: @KyleKanos The experiment is designed such that touchers for only one set link. for the other they do not. so one set has a closed circuit, the other has an open circuit. This is the main problem. So the circuit is what makes the question tough.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: You need to have a closed loop for current to flow. From your drawing, there will only be a closed loop if *both* touchers from *both* sets are connected. This won't happen due to length contraction. Well, at least unless the condition Phonon gives of $d\leq10/\gamma - L$ is met.

Comment: @KyleKanos "if both touchers from both sets are connected" are you sure?! set No. 1 will see that the circuit is closed. Well I have a similar question about this: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128520/ The accepted answer with its valuable comments confirm that lamp 1 will light.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: Just because *you* clicked the check mark does not mean that the answer actually is correct, it's just the one *you* found most helpful.

Comment: @KyleKanos well that seemed most reasonable answer (including its convincing comments). So if that's incorrect what is the correct answer and how do you convince me?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus from the figure and from your initial description, the only way a closed circuit is established is if all 4 touchers are in contact at the same time, and it's based on this knowledge that I replied to your post.

Comment: @Phonon: "in contact at the same time". *at the same time* is completely vague. simultaneity depends on the frame one chooses. For set No. 1 they will be in contact at the same time but for set No. 2  they will not.

Comment: No, this is exactly where the problem is different than the usual questions of simultaneity in SR, e.g. Alice holding two flash lights in a moving train, for her the lights will reach her at the same time, for someone at rest in station one of them will reach her first. Here it's different because the whole scenario is dependent on both frames, added to which we have a very strict condition on closed-ciruit establishment, so from one set, the other one is shorter, and vice-versa, which is why I brought up the idea of $d$, which allows an spacing of at least 10m even after contraction.

Comment: Minimus, I removed you bounty in the mistaken impression that this was a duplicate of [your older post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128520/2451). Fee free to re-instate it and please accept my apologies.

Comment: @dmckee: no problem. btw, please recover initial comments in http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/128527/56257 if possible.

Comment: This question is making less and less sense due to the constant changes. Voting to close because it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Drawing from the pole and barn paradox resolution. Clearly there isn't enough time for the information that the leads are connected in any frame to make a trip around the circuit. As such, parts of the circuit will always see the circuit as still closed in any frame. Therefore, the light will never turn on.

Comment: @Jim: So do you think none of the light will turn on?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus yes, that's what I think. It's like light-like separation. Not enough time for a causal reaction to the event. I'm pretty sure this is an all or nothing thing

Comment: @Minimus Heximus [Aug 7 at 3:25]: "_I deleted my comments._" -- Thanks for letting me and everyone know about that. Myself, however, I prefer my comments to stand; including those I had submitted here prior to _Aug 7 at 3:25_. (Hope this helps.) p.s. Sorry, I didn't have the chance to respond earlier to your comment of _Aug 7 [2014] at 3:25_

Comment: @user12262: I think I have to give up. There are horribly different personal opinions about  what will happen in this experiment. Just a real experiment can be trusted.

Comment: @Minimus Heximus: "_I think I have to give up. [...] opinions about what'll happen in this experiment. Just a real experiment can be trusted._" -- In science it holds, as Bohr put it: ["_that in each case we must be able to communicate to others what we have done and what we have learned_"](http://archive.org/stream/AtomicPhysicsHumanKnowledge/Bohr-AtomicPhysicsHumanKnowledge_djvu.txt); and Einstein has provided the necessary means as far as RT is concerned, namely the basic notion ("coincidence") which may be considered sufficiently self-evident and unambiguous. So **don't give up** on that!

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that you are assuming that the information about the circuit being closed is transmitted instantaneously to all point, but clearly this cannot be the case as you are then sending information faster than light. When the touchers connect there will be a pulse of current that will propagate around the circuit at some finite speed. When one of the pulses passes a lamp, it will flash. Therefore **both** lamps will flash and the **battery will be depleted** accordingly, **regardless of whether either observer thought that the circuit was ever closed**.

In normal circuit theory we don't worry about this kind of effect because electrical signals travel at the speed of light in the wire (for copper about two thirds the speed of light in a vacuum) so it all happen much too fast to observe, but for relativity this kind of thing has to be taken into account. Similar considerations apply in a non-relativistic settings in power grids, where the wires are so long that we can no longer ignore the finite speed of electrical signal, and we have to use the [Telegraph Line equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line_equations)

---

Edit: To give a slightly fuller explanation than I have been able to give in the comments, **If you have just arrived on this question you can ignore the rest of this, at least until you have read the comments on this answer**. Lets think about what an electric current is namely a *flow of charge*. That is it. Electron in the wire moving in one direction. There is nothing in this definition that requires a closed circuit. If you have a closed circuit then charged electrons can flow around in a loop and can happily do this for as long as you like. If you don't have a closed circuit however then as the charge flows it's going to have to build up at the end of the wire. Like charges repel each other, so a build up of charge will push back on any other charges still flowing up towards them, and this will cause the current to stop. In practice the electrons in a wire generally move very little but that small movement will lead to a small bunching or spreading out of electrons. This will lead to a change in the electric field around the electron, pushing on nearby electrons, changing the field around them. The effect of this is that the disturbance in the wire will propagate at close to the speed at which the change in the electric field can propagate, that is the speed of light.

For everyday purposes this means that electrons move about to find an equilibrium incredibly quickly, so these currents in open circuits will disappear almost instantly when a connection is made or broken, so we ignore them and only worry about currents in closed circuits which last long enough for us to measure. In relativity, however, we do have to worry about these effects because, as you realised in asking your question, people in different reference frames cannot always agree on whether a circuit was closed or not, so any theory that depends critically on whether or not a circuit is complete cannot be consistent with relativity. We have to worry about the fact electric disturbances are not transmitted instantly but move at some finite speed less than $c$.

Even though there may or may not be a complete circuit in a given reference frame in the situation you described, when the contacts are made there will be a difference in potential between the electrons on each side of the contact due to the connection of one side with the battery. This will cause a current to flow *at that point in the wire* which will then propagate along the wire. If the contact is broken before the pulse of current can make it round the circuit, the pulse will keep going and will still provide energy to light the lamp. (you can almost think of it like a "sound wave of electrons") After bouncing around for a (very short) bit the pulse of current will have dissipated its energy and the wire will again have no current in it. This will happen on both sides of the contact, with a pulse of "bunched up" electrons on one side and a pulse of "spread out" electrons on the other, so all the relevant components (both lamps and the battery) will come into contact with the signal.

Comment: "Your problem is that you are assuming that the information about the circuit being closed is transmitted instantaneously to all point" this is correct but it is marginal. the touchers are not a sharp point. Also by enlarging the lengths it may be possible to let the closed circuit persist for 10 seconds for example. So please ignore it. The question is about sources of energy.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something majorly important here, there's no way something moving at $10^5$ m/s can stay in contact with a 10 m long board for 10 s

Comment: @KyleKanos "by enlarging" $10$ m to  $10^5$ m and using larger touchers it may.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: That drastically changes your question though. It's going from a well-constrained problem to complete and utter BS.

Comment: "That drastically changes" No. As noted numbers are unimportant. The situation is the question. change numbers if they are not good as you wish as long as the situation described persists,

Comment: My point is that the idea that you need a closed circuit for electric current is only an approximation and does not hold in relativity. The electrical power which is providing energy to the lamps is coming from the battery in all cases. If the contact is maintained for an extended period of time, then you have a longer pulse of current and are closer to the classical approximation, in which the source of the energy is clearly the battery.

Comment: @BySymmetry: Can you tell me which lamps will turn on in the situation described?

Comment: As I said in my answer, both lights will flash.

Comment: Why will lamp 2 flash while in frame No. 2 there has been no closed circuit? How can it light in an open circuit?

Comment: Firstly whether or not the lamp flashes is necessarily frame independent. When and where it flashes might change based on your frame of reference, but not if. Secondly you don't need a closed circuit for an electric current to flow and transmit energy. Without a closed circuit the current will flow for an incredibly short time, which is why we normally ignore this effect, but if you want to consider relativity the simple approximations of circuit theory fail and you have to fall back to the more general electromagnetism.

Comment: "you don't need a closed circuit for an electric current to flow and transmit energy" OK, this seems to be a start of a scientific answer. Suppose your are in Set 2. you'll see a wire coming with a high velocity which is too short to close the circuit. But it closes. That seems reasonable. Can you explain this with formulas or with more convincing details about how this can happen? (a silimar well-known experiment, a wikipedia page, a paper, etc can be convincing).

Comment: btw, I don't understand why electrons pass throught a wire (=set 2) when only one toucher is connected to it.

Comment: I should re-read your answer tomorrow. It seemed to be reasonable. btw, it seems strange: for set 1 the circuit is closed for an interval of time (which can be elongated if the numbers change appropriately) but the lamp will just flash. I thought one of these will happen: 1) no lamps will light, 2) both will light, 3) just one will light. But flashing was not something I could imagine

Comment: Yes you will get a number of distinct flashes, which is not what you would immediately expect. This is starting to descend into a detailed discussion of what happens when a current flows in a wire, which isn't really in the spirit of your original question about relativity. I think you should potentially ask a separate question about the details of how electric current works, what a voltage is and why you will get a current pulse in both parts of the setup and leave this question of the relativity side of things. (though that may not be an easy question to formulate, so I'll keep an eye out)

Comment: The only real thing to add from the relativity point of view is that once you have this idea that a current pulse emanates from each point of contact, in the rest frame of the wire that pulse moves at the speed of light in the metal. You can then use the normal formulae for the transformations of positions, times and velocities in special relativity

Comment: I read again. Still a vague situation. I have asked this question that which lamp will light several times on the internet. Everyone has a different scenario about which lamp will light (e.g. see [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/128527/56257) answer for example). Really confusing. btw, the argument about flashing and electrons seems reasonable (=I cannot claim anything is wromg with it although it is vague for me). you transformed the question for me  to "How electrons move in this situation in each frame?". I should read more about how electrons move in relativistic situations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16321/discussion-between-by-symmetry-and-minimus-heximus).

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to the original version of the question, since then the question has gone through continuous editions, which may or may not have been taken into account when answering this.

As I don't understand what is meant by **"slow down"** in the OP, I assume it was meant to ask whether the battery will do work, in other words whether the circuit will ever be closed and create a difference of potential on either of the lamps, so here we go:

Firstly, a speed of $10^5 m/s \approx 0.0003c$ is far from reaching the relativistic limit, but anyway let's assume that it is important enough to take the relativistic effects into account.

Secondly there must be two sides to this question, one where the plates of the so called touchers in set No. 1 are taken as point like, and one where they have a finite length. Because in the first case, the alignment of all 4 touchers becomes a binary event (either touched or not) whereas with finite lengths, the 4 can be in contact but not necessarily in contact with the centers of the plates (of touchers).

Considering the first case, to me the claim that the observer in set No.1 will see his lamp light up is strange, because for either observers in No.1 and No.2, the length of the other set will be not be the same as their own, so a simultaneous contact cannot be observed in either cases. So because of [length contraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction) in special relativity, an observer in set No.1 will measure a distance $L=10m$ between his touchers and measure a length of $L'=L/\gamma$ between the touchers of the moving frame, vice-versa for set No.2. So because we have two spatially separated events and additionally are dependent on both frames, none of them will see any of the lamps light up as the circuit will never be closed for either observers.
$$\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$ 
$$L'=10m*\sqrt{1-\frac{(10^5)^2}{(3*10^8)^2}}\approx9.9999m$$

In the second case, where the plates in set No.1 have a finite length $d$, where although (as before) lengths of the sets are not the same, depending on $v$ a simultaneous contact between the 4 touchers can still take place. Because then the maximum effective length between the touchers of set No.1 becomes $L+d$ and you can see that then for plates of length: $$d\ge\frac{10}{\gamma}-L$$

The observed contracted set $(L+d)/\gamma$ (from the rest frame) will exhibit points on its plates spaced $10m$ so the circuit can become closed. But even then I don't think the question is still solved, because now the simultaneity of the established electric field and the current propagation remain to be resolved. Knowing the electric field establishes itself at the speed of light, and that the two sets are at a relative speed of $0.0003c$ we can probably assume that there's enough time for the electric field(signal) to be established throughout the closed circuit, but even then the drift current travels at much lower speeds, depending on the dielectric constant of the wires, and its speed in one part of the circuit will be different than the other because of the relative motion sets, if we take its speed at $v_d$ in the frame at rest, in the other set it will be at (Lorentz transformations): $$v_d'=\frac{v_d-v}{1-\frac{vv_d}{c^2}}$$

We already know that the lamps cannot be turned on at the same time, and additionally for one of the observers to finally see both lamps on at some point in time (not simultaneously), the connection time of touchers will be decisive, as it has to last at least for one cycle of the current.

Finally depending on the direction of the current, in the second case (plate-like touchers) both observers will see the very same lamp go on each time and the battery will be doing work then, assuming the condition of $d$ is fulfilled.

Comment: The length of touchers are so short so that a circuit has enough time to light up lamps. Is the length of touchers really important? And do you think either both lamps will light or none of them will light?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus yes the length of the touchers and the relative speed are the only two important factors here. Again as I said they need to have a finite length which fulfills the length contraction condition imposed by Lorentz transformations, otherwise all 4 contacts will not be established at once for the circuit to be closed. Now once we have fulfilled the condition on $d$, then the question is "for how long will the connection last? so that the current will run through the circuit at least once?" which again only depends on $v$ and $d$.

Comment: the smaller $v$ the liklier the two lamps will light up and observed by both sets, of course they will never light up simultaneously. On the other hand, if d is very small, then only one of the lamps will light up, based on the direction of the current. This can be easily worked out if we fix some value for the drift current, for d and for $v$.

Comment: "then only one of the lamps" do you mean lamp in set No. 1? What is the course of energy it uses to light?

Comment: the battery in a closed circuit establishes a difference of potential between the two contacts of the lamp and a current runs through, now the lamp No.1 is turned on if the current is counterclockwise if I'm not mistaken. This is just a matter of circuitry detail, the only interesting element for us was to conclude whether the battery will do work on not, your original question. And we concluded that regardless of which lamp in either sets is turned on, the battery will have done work.

Comment: That is my paradox. the battery will never feel a closed circuit. Because it located in Set 2. So for battery frame, the situation is the same as when all wires are removed from it. How can it lose energy. It seems impossible.

Comment: I'm afraid you're going in circles, I just suggest you read through my answers carefully once again, and mull over the scenarios discussed on your own for a bit, I am sure most of your confusions will be resolved. If you will still find yourself puzzled, I will further assist you.

Comment: I'll re-examine it tomorrow. Really I was confused with considering $d$ while it seems unimportant to me and I wanted to check if my question is understood correctly. this comment to be deleted.

Comment: " the length of the other set will be not be the same as their own" you have ignored **note 1** (existing before the complementary notes). The 10 m for set No. 2 is not its proper length it is the relativistic length that an observer in set 1 observes. The experment is designed such that only for one set the circuit is to be closed. That's the main situation the experiment is to create and the question relates to this situation.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus I have discussed two cases in my answer, the second one already discusses what your "first note" refers to. As for your statement "only one set of the circuit will be closed": you had not specified such thing in your OP, and as I have said in my answer I will not further adapt my answer to your ever changing scenarios. If you're not satisfied with the answer I provided for your OP, so be it, I will not spend any further time on this. I hope in future before you post a question, you will first take the time to clearly make up your mind and only then post it.

Comment: Note the original question never changed. Just some explanation were added to make the question clear (because the comments showed that some things should be emphasized). The question has not changed at all.

Comment: The discussion on electric movement direction was interesting.

Answer (score 1):

> **My Question**: Will set No. 2 slow down?

No, why would it? There is no mechanism by which a **wire** can transform *kinetic energy* to an **electric current**, so there is no possible way for Set 1 to absorb Set 2's energy to slow it down. Thus, $v$ remains its velocity after contact.

*If* Set 1's lights light up (and I'm not convinced it does), then Set 2's light must *also* light up because the circuit will have been closed & both lights are connected to the circuit. While simultaneity is not necessarily held between observers, the observers must agree on the results that both lights were lit (logical consistency argument here).

Since we've already ruled out the bogus kinetic energy$\to$current idea, then the only way for the lights to turn on is via the battery.

Comment: Which lamp will light if the circuit will be closed for set 1 and will not be closed for set 2?

Comment: but for set 1 both are 10 as noted in the question, the proper length of sets are not the same.

Comment: Either way, I don't believe the lights would illuminate. The closed loop would get opened too quickly.

Comment: I need some scientific convincing reasoning. Btw, I'm not sure if you know the main details of the question.

Comment: Besides, your main question is: *Will set No. 2 slow down?* I've answered your question with a clear no. You have to explain why on earth *would* it slow down.

Comment: See note 4. btw, it is not important what you believe. What you prove is important, btw, you even do not get the question. probably you do not have a relativistic mind,

Comment: Note 4 doesn't even make sense, how can a **wire** transform *kinetic energy* into electricity?

Comment: but there is a reason that the battery cannot be used. There is not any other source except the kinetic energy.

Comment: So if it can't use the battery and transfer of energy to electricity isn't possible with a wire, then the **obvious** conclusion is ...... ? (waiting for you to answer it)

Comment: there is another problem. lamp 1 will feel two ends of a battery connected to its ends. In this situation How can it remain off?

Comment: Because you assume (erroneously) instantaneous current, when a signal must be processed. As I stated before, the closed loop will exist for too short a duration for current to flow.

Comment: I explained a few minutes that this short duration can be a few seconds by extending the lengths. If you do not stick to the dummy unimportant numbers I have entered carelessly.

Comment: If we don't stick to the dummy numbers, then I can say that since $v=0$ m/s, they never go off because 1 & 2 are separated by too great a distance. Or I can say $v=10^{-14}$ m/s so that they will remain in contact for some amount of time (of course, after a very long time). Believe it or not, your "dummy unimportant" numbers *actually **are** important*.

Comment: You're asking about a SR situation, you cannot ignore *relativistic speeds*, so you *ought* to define $v$ (to at least be relativistic, having it be 0.0003 c isn't really relativistic, you should set it to something like 0.1 c). Sure $\ell$ doesn't matter, but $v$ certainly does.

Comment: yes this was the number in the picture and I could not change it easily. v in fact should be 100,000 km/s. btw, for 100000m/s can be acceptable if sets are longer. however, the situation is described, So forget the numbers an assume they are properly chosen.

Comment: I deleted a few comments that were obsolete and/or a little rude.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is best analyzed in a reference frame in which both sets are moving, toward each other, at the same speed: this is a reference frame (with reference to Fig. 1) moving leftward at speed $v = 50 km/s$.

In this frame relativistic contractions are identical, thus the circuit will close. Also, it will be closed for a time long with respect to the system's light -crossing time because the speed is large but surely not relativistic (this is the whole reason why such speed was chosen), so that we may assume a proper current will be circulating through the circuit.

Since the current is not steady, there will be induction fields, thus also a Poynting flux leaving the two sets. However, in the c.o.m. reference frame where we placed ourselves, because of the system symmetry, there will be no net impulse lost in any direction.

However, once we abandon this special reference frame and go back to the reference frame of the OP (that of set 1), *relativistic beaming* appears: in other words, photons leaving the system will be preferentially bunched along the direction of motion of the reference frame in which they have $P_x = P_y = 0$ in the average, *i.e.*, in the direction of motion of set 2.

Since part of the initial impulse of the set 2 is now lost to photons, it will have to slow down.

Answer (score 0):

The transformation between frames is $$x'=\gamma(x-vt)$$
So, the endpoints 0 and L in frame F transform into :

$$x'_1=\gamma(0-vt)$$
$$x'_2=\gamma(L-vt)$$

in frame F'. But the location of the "touches" in frame F' is

$$x'_1=-L$$and 
$$x'_2=0$$, respectively

So:

$$-L=\gamma(0-vt_1)$$
$$0=\gamma(L-vt_2)$$

i.e.

$$t_1=\frac{L}{\gamma v}$$
$$t_2=\frac{L}{v}$$

So, $$t_1 \ne t_2$$, i.e. the circuit NEVER closes. Not in frame F, neither in frame F'. No "paradox".

On the other hand, if you arrange such that :

$$x'_1=-\gamma L$$ and 
$$x'_2=0$$, respectively, then

$$t_1=t_2=\frac{L}{v}$$

so, the circuit closes in BOTH frame F and frame F'. STILL, no "paradox".  Just your confusion about how relativity works.