# Relativity of Simultaneity - confusion regarding the ordering of events when taking different inertial frames as the origin

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, thought-experiment

I'll admit my question steals a graphic from this user's [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/128131/relativity-of-simultaneity-example-in-resnick) here, but it is a different question regarding the same scenario that struck confusion of mine. Here is the graphic, illustrating the property of Relativity of Simultaneity:

[image]

I completely agree with the implications here with $S'$ moving relative to $S$. Since light moves at a fixed speed, it would be paradoxical to suggest Sally would say light from both events reached her at the same time, but here is what confuses me:

Say we consider $S'$'s point of view. So instead of $S'$ moving at speed $v$ relative to $S$, $S$ moves at speed $-v$ relative to $S'$. This should be equally true. In that case, after events $A$ and $B$ occur, $S'$ remains in place relative to $S$ and $S$ moves to the left some, reversing the example in the graphic. In that case, $S$ should've received the light from $A$ first, then from $B$ just as $S'$ received light from $B$ first then $A$ when moving with velocity $v$ relative to $S$. And in this case, $S'$ receives both signals at the same time.

So, I've just created an argument that $S'$ and $S$ can receive both events at the same time if we consider their frame as the origin and everything else moving relative to it, and both can receive both events at different times if moving relative to a reference frame at the origin. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your logical flaw seems to be in the initial assumption that the events $A$ and $B$ happen simultaneously in both frames $S$ and $S^{'}$. If you reverse the argument, as you did, by assuming $S^{'}$ stationary, then either $A$ and $B$ are no longer simultaneous or, if you assume they are, then they are not the same events anymore, but $A^{'}$ and $B^{'}$.

Comment: (a) Why are they no longer simultaneous?  (b) Why are they no longer the same events anymore if I reverse the argument?

Comment: If you take the original argument, it shows that, if the $A$ and $B$ events are simultaneous in the frame  $S$, then they are not simultaneous in the frame $S^{'}$. This answers your (a) question of why these events are not simultaneous in the frame $S^{'}$. So, if you take any pair events that are simultaneous in the frame $S^{'}$, then they would not be the same events as $A$ and $B$, because $A$ and $B$ are not simultaneous in $S^{'}$.

Comment: Also it is to be noted that if clocks were positioned at A' and B', and the lightning strike lit up these clocks, the images from both clocks will reach O' at different times, and the two clock images seen at O' will indicate different times. This is because the time being indicated at clock A' is ahead of the time being indicated by the clock located at B'. Thus to O', it will still seem as thought the lightning struck at B' position first.